# AvalonDock: Binding to LayoutAnchorablePane position?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I am creating a custom theme for my WPF application that uses the [AvalonDock](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock) docking framework.
I have already opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/issues/312) for my question on the AvalonDock repo but I'm hoping I can get an answer faster here (and ready to put a bounty on this ASAP).

---

In my custom theme I have moved the tab items for the `LayoutAnchorablePane` to stack vertically on the left side, and the pane uses a Grid with column sizes `Auto, *, Auto`.
I would like to write a Trigger for the style that moves the tabs from the left column to the right column when the `LayoutAnchorablePane` is attached to the right side of the root layout panel. (So that the tabs are always on the outside)

Here is the relevant section of my theme's XAML that I am trying to put the trigger on. This is almost identical to the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` template from the generic.xaml style in AvalonDock:

```xml
<Grid
    ClipToBounds="true"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--  Following border is required to catch mouse events  -->
    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="Transparent" />
    <StackPanel
    x:Name="HeaderPanel"
    Width="40"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Panel.ZIndex="1"
    IsItemsHost="true"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
    <Border
    x:Name="ContentPanel"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="2"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
    <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
            ContentSource="SelectedContent"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ??? }">
        <Setter TargetName="HeaderPanel" Property="Grid.Column" Value="2"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

As far as I can tell, there is no property on `LayoutAnchorablePane` or any of its interfaces that exposes which side of the layout the pane is on. So I'm lost for what I can put in `{Binding ??? }` in my DataTrigger.

It seems like I need to implement the property myself and use my own builds of AvalonDock. I would like to avoid this if it's at all possible; So maybe there's some clever MarkupExtension or Converter idea I could implement in my own code? Maybe my assumption that this can be done with `DataTrigger` can be challenged too. I would be happy to use a completely code-behind solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to BionicCode for the really detailed answer, I ended up only needing a few hints from that answer to solve the problem in my own way. So I thought it would be worth sharing my code too.

---

`LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` inherits from `TabControl` so it already has the `TabStripPlacement` property that the style can bind to on its templated parent.

So the new style replaces `Grid` with `DockPanel` and looks like this:

```xml
<DockPanel
    ClipToBounds="true"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <!--  Following border is required to catch mouse events  -->
    <Border Background="Transparent" />
    <StackPanel
    x:Name="HeaderPanel"
    Width="40"
    DockPanel.Dock="{TemplateBinding TapStripPlacement}"
    Panel.ZIndex="1"
    IsItemsHost="true"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
    <Border
    x:Name="ContentPanel"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderThickness="2"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
    <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
            ContentSource="SelectedContent"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

Now this style will move the tabs to any of the sides (left/right/top/bottom) depending on the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl.TabStripPlacement` property.

In code behind (for the Window that has the DockingManager) I attached an event handler to `DockingManager.Layout.Updated` that runs the following method:

```cs
private void UpdateTabSides()
{
    foreach (LayoutAnchorablePaneControl apc in DockManager.LayoutRootPanel.FindLogicalChildren<LayoutAnchorablePaneControl>())
    {
        var side = apc.Model.GetSide();
        if (side == AnchorSide.Right)
        {
            apc.TabStripPlacement = Dock.Right;
        }
        else
        {
            apc.TabStripPlacement = Dock.Left;
        }
    }
}
```

I find this approach to be a lot simpler than BionicCode's answer but they deserve the bounty for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The AvalonDock implementation is pretty weird. I remember having some troubles too when I had to use this control in a project. I think I know this control quite well. It is very badly implemented, in my opinion. Because they, for some reason, decided to implement this control itself using MVVM instead of making it simply MVVM ready. This makes it very inconvenient to use in advanced scenarios.
Semantics are also quite confusing. For example, containers are not the controls that render data. Containers are assigned to the `Model` property of the controls. Data is not assigned to the `DataContext`. But it looks good.

Also, the tab header placement behavior is broken (only allows tab headers at the bottom). My fix could be of interest for you, especially in context of dynamic tab header placement. See the `Style` below to get the expected tab header placement behavior. It simply wraps the content of the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` into a `DockingPanel` and rotates the header host, so that you get tab header alignment you have in Visual Studio (stacked by width). That's all. If you wish to stack the headers by their height (no rotation) simply replace the `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` with a e.g., `StackPanel` and remove the rotation triggers.
The provided example is based on that `Style` below. Otherwise you won't be able to propagate tab header position to the view.

Another big pain is the lack of events that are exposed by the `DockingManager` class and AvalonDock in general. This means there is no chance to observe the drag and drop actions. As a matter of fact, `DockingManager` only exposes three quite uninteresting events. Same to the content hosts like the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl`.
Since AvalonDock does not use the WPF framework's Drag & Drop API, handling those events is not a solution.

To overcome the short comings, you must handle one of the few model events, the `LayoutRoot.Updated` event in this case.

The solution only targets the `LayoutAnchorablePane` and `LayoutAnchorableGroupPane`. To address advanced grouping or the `LayoutDocumentPane` you can simple extend the example by following the pattern.
Since you only require/requested a two column layout, the algorithm will do the job. Other more advanced layout arrangements are supported, but the behavior is not perfect as not all conditions are currently tracked. The focus is on a two column layout. It's a quick (but not so dirty) and very simple solution.
You should consider to disallow any layout arrangement other than the two column layout explicitly.

Additionally, AvalonDock does not provide an event to indicate when the visual layout process is completed. You only get a notification via the `LayoutRoot.Updated` event when the layout model is added/removed to/from the layout model tree. But you never know when exactly the visual tree is updated. We need to have access to the visual containers in order to set the `LayoutPanelControl.TabStripPlacement` property based on the new position of this control.
To overcome this, I used the `Dispatcher` to defer the access to the then initialized and rendered `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl`. Otherwise the tab header arrangement would be premature, because the control's layout index is yet to change. AvalonDock only allows to track very few layout model modifications but no observation of actual docking operations at all.

So the algorithm is basically

1. Handle the `LayoutRoot.Updated` event and start the actual positioning algorithm deferred using the Dispatcher
2. Iterate over all pane controls to update the tab header placement. In case nesting is allowed, you will have a layout tree that you have to traverse recursively, like it is done in this example for group panes.
3. Identify the position of the pane in the layout based on their index.
4. Set the `LayoutPanelControl.TabStripPlacement` property according to the index: an index of 0 means left and an index that equals the item count means right. Every other index is in between. The tab headers are placed based on the pane's position in the layout.
5. The DockingPanel will layout the tab items accordingly. Triggers are used to rotate the tab headers if they are positioned left or right.

There can be multiple `LayoutPanelControl` elements in the layout (except you disallow "illegal" layout arrangements to enforce the two column layout).

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private const Dock DefaultDockPosition = Dock.Bottom;

  private void InitializeOnDockingManager_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var dockingManager = sender as DockingManager;
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
      ArrangePanel(dockingManager.LayoutRootPanel);
    },
    DispatcherPriority.Background);

    dockingManager.Layout.Updated += OnLayoutUpdated;
  }

  private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var layoutRoot = sender as LayoutRoot;
    var dockingManager = layoutRoot.Manager;
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
      ArrangePanel(dockingManager.LayoutRootPanel);
    },
    DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
  }

  private void ArrangePanel(LayoutPanelControl layoutPanelControl)
  {
    IEnumerable<ILayoutControl> layoutControls = layoutPanelControl.Children
      .OfType<ILayoutControl>()
      .Where(control =>
        control is LayoutAnchorablePaneControl paneControl
          && (paneControl.Model as ILayoutContainer).Children.Any()
        || control is LayoutAnchorablePaneGroupControl or LayoutPanelControl);

    int paneControlCount = layoutControls.Count(control => control is not LayoutPanelControl);
    int paneControlLayoutPosition = 0;

    foreach (ILayoutControl layoutControl in layoutControls)
    {
      if (layoutControl is LayoutPanelControl layoutPanel)
      {
        ArrangePanel(layoutPanel);
        continue;
      }

      paneControlLayoutPosition++;
      bool isFirst = paneControlLayoutPosition == 1;
      bool isLast = paneControlCount == paneControlLayoutPosition;

      if (layoutControl is LayoutAnchorablePaneGroupControl paneGroupControl)
      {
        PositiontabHeadersInPaneGroup((isFirst, isLast), paneGroupControl);
      }
      else if (layoutControl is LayoutAnchorablePaneControl paneControl)
      {
        if (paneControlCount == 1)
        {
          paneControl.TabStripPlacement = DefaultDockPosition;
        }
        else
        {
          PositionTabHeadersInPane(paneControl, isFirst, isLast);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static void PositionTabHeadersInPane(LayoutAnchorablePaneControl paneControl, bool isFirst, bool isLast)
    => paneControl.TabStripPlacement =
      (isFirst, isLast) switch
      {
        (true, _) => Dock.Left,
        (_, true) => Dock.Right,
        _ => DefaultDockPosition
      };

  private void PositiontabHeadersInPaneGroup((bool IsGroupFirst, bool IsGroupLast) parentPaneGroupPosition, LayoutAnchorablePaneGroupControl paneGroupControl)
  {
    IEnumerable<ILayoutControl> groupMembers = paneGroupControl.Children
      .OfType<ILayoutControl>();
    int groupMemberCount = groupMembers.Count();
    int layoutPosition = 0;

    foreach (ILayoutControl groupMember in groupMembers)
    {
      layoutPosition++;
      bool isFirst = layoutPosition == 1;
      bool isLast = layoutPosition == groupMemberCount;

      if (groupMember is LayoutAnchorablePaneGroupControl childGroupControl)
      {
        PositiontabHeadersInPaneGroup((isFirst, isLast), childGroupControl);
      }
      else if (groupMember is LayoutAnchorablePaneControl paneControl)
      {
        (bool IsPaneFirstInGroup, bool IsPaneLastInGroup) panePositionInGroup = (isFirst, isLast);

        paneControl.TabStripPlacement =
          !parentPaneGroupPosition.IsGroupFirst && !parentPaneGroupPosition.IsGroupLast
          || groupMemberCount == 1
            ? DefaultDockPosition
            : (parentPaneGroupPosition, panePositionInGroup, paneGroupControl.Orientation) switch
            {
              ({ IsGroupFirst: true }, { IsPaneFirstInGroup: true }, Orientation.Horizontal) => Dock.Left,
              ({ IsGroupLast: true }, { IsPaneLastInGroup: true }, Orientation.Horizontal) => Dock.Right,
              ({ IsGroupFirst: true }, _, Orientation.Vertical) => Dock.Left,
              ({ IsGroupLast: true }, _, Orientation.Vertical) => Dock.Right,
              _ => DefaultDockPosition
            };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
The required `AnchorablePaneControlStyle` is defined below.

```xml
<xcad:DockingManager Loaded="InitializeOnDockingManager_Loaded"
                     AnchorablePaneControlStyle="{StaticResource AnchorablePaneControlStyle}"
                     Height="500"
                     Width="500"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <xcad:LayoutRoot>
    <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="properties"
                               Title="Properties">
          <TextBlock Text="123abc" />
        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="AgendaLeft"
                               ContentId="agendaLeft">
          <TextBlock Text="Agenda Content" />
        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="ContactsLeft"
                               ContentId="contactsLeft">
          <TextBlock Text="Contacts Content" />
        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
      </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </xcad:LayoutPanel>
  </xcad:LayoutRoot>
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

**AnchorablePaneControlStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="AnchorablePaneControlStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneControl}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
  <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement"
          Value="Bottom" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneControl}">
        <Grid ClipToBounds="true"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
          
          <!--Following border is required to catch mouse events-->
          <Border Background="Transparent"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2" />
          
          <DockPanel>
            <xcad:AnchorablePaneTabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                         DockPanel.Dock="{TemplateBinding TabStripPlacement}"
                                         Margin="2,0,2,2"
                                         IsItemsHost="true"
                                         KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                         KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle">
              <xcad:AnchorablePaneTabPanel.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="TabPanelRotateTransform" />
              </xcad:AnchorablePaneTabPanel.LayoutTransform>
            </xcad:AnchorablePaneTabPanel>
            
          <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" DockPanel.Dock="{TemplateBinding TabStripPlacement}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"                                    
                                ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
          </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement"
                   Value="Top">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LeftTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RightTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BottomTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="TopTabStripPlacementAnimation">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabPanelRotateTransform"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="90"
                                   Duration="0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement"
                   Value="Bottom">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LeftTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="TopTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RightTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="BottomTabStripPlacementAnimation">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabPanelRotateTransform"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="0"
                                   Duration="0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement"
                   Value="Left">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="TopTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RightTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BottomTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="LeftTabStripPlacementAnimation">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabPanelRotateTransform"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="90" 
                                   Duration="0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement"
                   Value="Right">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LeftTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="TopTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="BottomTabStripPlacementAnimation" />
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="RightTabStripPlacementAnimation">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TabPanelRotateTransform"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                   To="90"
                                   Duration="0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

  <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding ToolTip}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
              <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
              </Grid>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected"
                         Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background"
                          Value="White" />
                  <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                          Value="1" />
                  <Setter Property="Margin"
                          Value="0,-1,-1,-2" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                               Value="true" />
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected"
                               Value="false" />
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GradientInactiveCaptionBrushKey}}" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                  <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                          Value="0" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                         Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=Items.Count, FallbackValue=1}"
                       Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

  <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <xcad:LayoutAnchorableTabItem Model="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
          Value="{StaticResource AnchorablePaneControlContentTemplate}" />

</Style>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` was inherited from a `TabControl`. That means I can bind to `TabStripPlacement` and control that from codebehind. Your answer goes in to a lot of detail but I ended up only needing one thing to help me: The async invoke from `Layout.Updated` to give the visual tree time to update.

Comment: Yes, they extend TabControl. But the the `TabStripPlacement` is broken. That's why I have used a `DockingPanel` as panel host in the `Style`. The original tab item layout only supports `Dock.Bottom` (by accident I guess). The contro doesn't seem to be tested very well. Didn't see any uint tests too. But it's free. Maybe the paid version fixes some issues.

Comment: There is no paid version for the fork I mentioned above. This is Dirkster.AvalonDock, not Xceed WPF Toolkit

Comment: Also the generic theme is responsible for "breaking" the `TapStripPlacement`. They do not provide a template that binds to the property so it's just unused entirely while the tabs are manually positioned at the bottom due to the template's `Grid`. In my answer I used a `DockPanel` too to re-connect to that property. I bet the default WPF control template does this too.

Comment: Alrigh, I see. The fork appears to suffer from the same issues, The `AnchorablePaneControlStyle` Style is still broken. Crucial events are still not implemented. I have just reviewed some sources. So the answer is still valid, although I have to admit that I was expecting you to use the original XCEED AvalonDoc library. But there is a paid XCEED version. Not sure how much it has improved. Never used the paid version.

Comment: No the, the default template is identical, except it uses the TabPanel. This panel is responsible for aligning the TabItem based on their TabStripPlacement property, which is set by the TabControl.

Comment: So, AvalonDock's bad implementation of the AnchorablePaneTabPanel is the true problem. Using a DockingPanel is just a workaround.

Comment: The `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` is just a child that arranges tab items, it doesn't move itself. If you read my original question closely I replaced that with StackPanel so I could easily arrange them vertically. (That works fantastic but you have to re-implement drag & drop functionality)
What I'm talking about is the template for `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl`, it is a replacement for the default WPF `TabControl` template (that is what you get implicitly when you inherit from it) and entirely ignores the `TabStripPlacement` property, which means setting that property doesn't move the strip.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bad implementation. It's a deliberate decision for the theme to always put tabs on the bottom and disregard the `TabStripPlacement` property. You can completely "fix" it by making your own theme, which is what I did. No changes needed in the original library to get the normal TabControl functionality back; Just need a theme that respects `TabStripPlacement`.

Comment: I know. But in the original `TabControl` it's not the template layout that is responsible for the tab positioning but the `TabPanel` itself. AvalonDock replaced the `TabPanel` with their own `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` which does not calculate the TabItem positions. The positions are hard coded in the layout. That's the mistake here. Their `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` should calculate the `TabItem` positions based on their `TabStripPlacement` value too.

Comment: It's bad, because it's unexpected. Their panes expose the TabStripPlacement property. So you would expect it to have a function.

Comment: But that's just the theme, it's not "broken", just arbitrarily ignored by the theme's design. There are other themes that probably use `TabStripPlacement`, I just never checked them. I would only go as far as saying the default `generic.xaml` theme is a bad example to learn from because all of its control templates are highly customized to a certain look & layout similar to Visual Studio's docking.

Comment: The `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` is broken. It is broken because their control API suggest that you can assign a `Dock` enum value to the `TabStripPlacement` property. But this property is totally ignored. That's my point. It doesn't take much to implement the panel properly so that the API is not broken anymore. API should never have NoOp members. That's silly and leads to a lot of confusion. It's not clean. In terms of the API it is broken. We have to review the source code to understand the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're understanding me. I'm not even using `AnchorablePaneTabPanel`. It doesn't exist in this theme at all. I replaced it with `StackPanel`. The only problem is where that StackPanel is put in the layout. It does not decide for itself where it should go, the template for the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` shown in my question is what decides where it should go. Using `DockPanel` instead of `Grid` allows me to set `DockPanel.Dock` on the StackPanel and put it on any side now. This is clearly just a shortcoming in the default template because it uses `Grid`.

Comment: I understand that your Style is responsible to position the tabs. I see. I thought we are discussing the original AvalonDock (fork) implementation. In your comment you were clearly referring to the original design stating *"They do not provide a template that binds to the property so it's just unused entirely while the tabs are manually positioned at the bottom due to the template's Grid"* and *"I bet the default WPF control template does this too."* -

Comment: I was just explaining how the `TabControl` layout is handled by the `TabPanel` and not the template's layout. I was calling the `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` buggy as it breaks the expected behavior making the `TabStripPlacement` useless. I know that you have replaced it with a `StackPanel`.

Comment: In the case of the `generic.xaml` style given with AvalonDock, they use `Grid` which cannot use a `Dock` side enum to position its children. The style puts the `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` in a fixed Grid row and ignores the `TabStripPlacement` property on the base `TabControl`. This is just a bad style, because it ignores useful properties on the base. You may be right that the `TabPanel` does its own positioning in the WPF native templates but in AvalonDock they have completely overriden the whole TabControl and moved the responsibility to that template.

Comment: My only argument here is that the library, it's API, and the code are fine. It's just the default theme with its control templates that "breaks" the API because it does not bind to `TabStripPlacement` and overrides the layout behaviours that the native WPF template for `TabControl` (which uses `TabPanel`) would have. With a new theme you can restore this functionality.

Comment: Almost. The `Grid` only arranges the content (the `ContentPresenter`) of the `TabControl` (`LayoutAnchorablePaneControl`) and the tab headers (the `Panel`). This layout they have copied from the original `TabControl` style. But the `AnchorablePaneTabPanel` does not know how to arrange items - it simply renders them in place, which is the second row of the `Grid` layout. That's why `TabStripPlacement` i.e. dynamic layout is broken. That's why I say the code is broken: setting the `TabStripPlacement` has absolutely no effect.

Comment: To fix this, we must override the original template or provide oure own `Panel` implementation. If the fixed tab header placement is on purpose, then the `LayoutAnchorablePaneControl` shouldn't expose the `TabStripPlacement` property or override the property changed handler to throw a `NotSupportedException`. Then the intend is clear and clients of this library would not try to use it and therefore erxperience a bug. In the end this is a badly designed library. I know that it is free and since there is a paid version the efforts are limited.

Comment: I wonder what you would say if you have to override the default style of e.g. `ListBox` in order to make it work properly.

Comment: Obviously, we have a different opinion how a good API should be designed. it seems that you are fine to implement an API that exposes members with no functionality - silently - where the client has to take action in order to make the API work as expected. I don't know any good library where this is the principle.

Comment: I think a properly implemented panel or style would be the state of the art to allwo positioning the tab headers as expected. It is not the resposibility of the client to inspect the internals to identify the problem and fix it.

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad I could help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help. One final comment from me too just to shine some light on my point of view: AvalonDock decided that the anchorable pane should use `TabControl` but then gave us a default style with an unusual template for `TabControl`. The problem is just the style. The API works if the style actually binds to the API. If I were to make a PR to AvalonDock to fix this I wouldn't change code to remove the API, I would change the template `generic.xaml` theme to look like my answer to this question. The theme included with the library is the only reason that the "API doesn't work".

Comment: *"The API works if the style actually binds to the API"* - that's the point: **if**. As it is, the API doesn't work. You are right, there are two ssoultions to the problem: a) fix the layout or implement the panel properly or b) remove the TabStripPlacement  or throw an exception if the behavior is explicitly not wanted by the author. I don't know what was on the mind of the author. I only know, right now, the API does *not* work. We have to investigate *why* it is not working, just to come to the conclusion it would be the simplest to override the default style to improve the layout.

Comment: I'm happy for any libary that is ready to use without such investigations. That's what I would call standard in terms of quality :)